# Async method crashes with an exception on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am using the Map functionality of Windows Phone 8.1 to find a route with the following code:

```
MapRouteFinderResult routeResult = null;

try
{
    if (true == typeOfTransport.Equals(GlobalDeclarations.TypeOfTransport.Walk))
    {
        routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetWalkingRouteAsync(startPoint, endPoint);
    }
    else
    {
        routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(startPoint, endPoint, MapRouteOptimization.Time, MapRouteRestrictions.None, 290);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The problem is that despite the try-catch, this `MapRouteFinder.GetWalkingRouteAsync` method crashes with an exception: `Object not set to an instance of an object`. Both `startPoint` and `endPoint` params are obviously not null, and filled with data. Why is this? And why the whole app crashes instead of catching the exception in the try-catch section?

Comment: Is the `MapRouteFinder` class null? have you tried debugging and seeing the exact line that is throwing the exception? The reason that it wouldn't be caught is if the exception is being thrown further up the stack rather in your try/catch block.

Comment: How should i know? It's a system class. I don't get it

Comment: OK, where is the exception being thrown?

Comment: In a system class App.g.i.cs in some UnhandledException handler

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see where it's getting thrown? are you 100% sure the exception is getting thrown inside the `MapRouteFinder`?

Comment: I am not sure. I don't know how to debug a system class

Comment: The problem is probably not in the code you show : there is try/catch. Have a look in your App.xaml. It seems there is a problem deserialize it. Start with F5 for debugging, wait the exception, and when you it crashes look in the Watch and local Windows for detailed information